# Using nested loops to analyse up-regulated and down-regulated genes

Tags: r, dplyr, bioinformatics

I am new to R Programming and I am currently looking to analyse a huge dataset of genes. I am attempting to alter a nested loop that currently works to see which genes are up-regulated given varying adjusted P values and LogFC values to see the same but for down-regulated genes. What I have generated for the up-regulated genes is a 4x4 table looking to see how the number of genes that meet the cut off values I have selected for the P adjusted value and the LogFC varies. [The image shows the coding used for the nested loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC0Fn.jpg) What I am getting when I attempt to execute this for the down-regulated genes is the same values - I am assuming R is not registering any changes and returns the same numbers. 
Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
 #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Function to calculate number of up regulated genes
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
get.upregulated.genes <- function(dafra, p.value.max, log.fc.min) {
  gene.count <- subset(dafra, adj.P.Val <= p.value.max & logFC >= log.fc.min) %>% 
    .[["Gene.symbol"]] %>% unique %>% length
  return(gene.count)
}

get.upregulated.genes(dafra=df3, p.value.max=0.05, log.fc.min=1) # 429

p.values <- c(0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.05)
log.fcs <- rev(c(0.5, 1, 1.5, 2))
log.fcs
mx.up <- matrix(rep(NA, 16), ncol=4)
mx.up
colnames(mx.up) <- p.values
rownames(mx.up) <- log.fcs

for (x in p.values) {
  for (y in log.fcs) {
    z <- get.upregulated.genes(df3, x, y)
    mx.up[as.character(y),as.character(x)] <- z
  }
}
mx.up
View(mx.up)

for (x in p.values) {
  for (y in log.fcs) {
    z <- get.upregulated.genes(df3, x, y)
    print(x)
    print(y)
    print(z)
    print("------")
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it ok to paste the code in to the question, please?

Comment: Yes sure, please access it from the question above

Answer (score 1):

No need for `forloops`, try something like this (not tested, as there is no example data):

```
# get all combos
x <- expand.grid(
  p.values = c(0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.05),
  log.fcs = rev(c(0.5, 1, 1.5, 2)))

# loop rowby then get length of unique genes
apply(x, 1, function(i){
  length(unique(df3[ df3$adj.P.Val <= i[ 1 ] & df3$logFC >= i[ 2 ], "Gene.symbol" ]))
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately the second park did not work -  Error in `[.data.frame`(df3, df3$adj.P.Val <= i[1] & logFC >= i[2], "Gene.symbol") : 
  object 'logFC' not found. This is the message that came up, any ideas what I need to alter?

Comment: Second time lucky! Thank you so much, just one final question if you don't mind. How can I carry this out a second time round for the down regulated genes? What I find is that when R executes the command, I get the same values as the up regulated genes so I am assuming I need to make it clear somehow that I now want the genes that are down regulated to be used?

Comment: @HibaAl-khaffaji please define what you mean by "down regulated genes". It would make it so much easier if you can provide example input data, and expected output.

Comment: I am looking at a huge gene expression dataset from GEO2R (GSE108363) - In the RScript I have been working on I have written code to extract genes that are up regulated and down regulated  # Upregulated genes:
up.df <- subset(df3, adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & logFC >= 1)
# Downregulated genes:
down.df <- subset(df3, adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & logFC <= -1) This is the code I used for that particular part.